# How to avoid running out of heap in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, memory-management

My Flutter app is running out of heap on some low-end devices. Often, I see exceptions like:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 850688 free bytes and 830KB until OOM, target footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.

The memory profiler is not showing any memory leaks and I have been very careful about releasing resources. I have also tried to follow all the standard memory management best practices. There are no long lists of large bitmaps, for example.

Can adjusting org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the top-level gradle.properties file help with this problem? Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik org.gradle.jvmargs is for your build process not the jvm of user device. For that you should be using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap